# Issues with PySpark, groupBy and count number of NULL

Tags: pyspark

There are some questions on this theme. However, I don't seam to get why this dosen't return anything.

Is there any flagrant misstake in this code snippet?

```
columns = ['col1', 'col2', 'col3']

amount_missing_df = df.groupby('country').agg(*[(count(when(col(c).isNull(), c))/count(lit(1))).alias(c) for c in columns])
amount_missing_df.show()
```

Comment: What are you getting in the output?

Comment: Empty columns. And there are plenty of Null.

Comment: Can you please provide some sample data to reproduce this issue? TBH. I don't see the problem with the code.

Comment: what you input df looks like, maybe add some example rows ?